# How can I add a check box column in my radGrid? And how do I show the expand button?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, grouping, radgrid

I'm learning Telerik and I have the following design I'm trying to do translated into English (I don't need you to help me translate, just with the design components):

[image: Excel]

So far I have this:

[image: Progress]

How can I add the `check box`? Also how do I get rid of those 3 blank `columns` before the `columns` that I created myself?

Here is my HTML code so far:

```html
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" Width="483px"> 

            <asp:Label ID="TreatmentCenter" Text="Treatment Center:         " runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <telerik:RadDropDownList RenderMode="Lightweight" DefaultMessage="Select City" DataTextField="City" ID="DDL1" runat="server"></telerik:RadDropDownList>
                 
            <br />
          
            <telerik:RadGrid RenderMode="Lightweight"
                ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                ShowGroupPanel="True" Height="148px" Width="462px">

            <MasterTableView EnableHierarchyExpandAll="true" DataKeyNames="OrderID">
                <DetailTables>
                    
                    <telerik:GridTableView EnableHierarchyExpandAll="true" DataKeyNames="ProductID" runat="server">
                        
                        <ParentTableRelation>
                            <telerik:GridRelationFields DetailKeyField="OrderID" MasterKeyField="OrderID" />
                        </ParentTableRelation>
                       
                         <Columns>
                            <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
                               
                            </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="ProductName" HeaderText="Product Name" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                                DataField="ProductName">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="ProductID" HeaderText="Product ID" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                                DataField="ProductID">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                                DataField="Quantity">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="Price" HeaderText="Price" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                                DataField="Price">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>                      
                            
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="Procurer" HeaderText="Procurer" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                                DataField="Procurer">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>   
                                           
                        </Columns>
                    
                    </telerik:GridTableView>                 
                
                </DetailTables>
                
                <Columns>
                     
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="OrderID" HeaderText="Order ID" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                                DataField="OrderID">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn> 

                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="DateOfOrder" HeaderText="Date Of Order" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                                DataField="DateOfOrder">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn> 

                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="OrderName" HeaderText="Order Name" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                                DataField="OrderName">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn> 

                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn SortExpression="OrderAddress" HeaderText="Order Address" HeaderButtonType="TextButton"
                                DataField="OrderAddress">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn> 

                </Columns>

            </MasterTableView>
           
            <ClientSettings Scrolling-AllowScroll="true">
                <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" />
                <Resizing AllowRowResize ="true" EnableRealTimeResize="true" ResizeGridOnColumnResize="false" />
            </ClientSettings>

            <GroupingSettings ShowUnGroupButton="true" />

        </telerik:RadGrid>

        </telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

Comment: Telerik has some good support option. You should ask this question on their forum too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out

```html
<Columns>
  <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn UniqueName="GridClientSelectColumn1" />
</Columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't read the arabic text so I am not sure how similar you need things to be (e.g., do you need them in RTL too), but I suggest the following:

- inspect the rendering and control structure of your sample
- try adding the controls you need and reorder them like any simple HTML elements

Here are some examples:

just add a checkbox:

```
            <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" Width="93px">
            <telerik:RadCheckBox runat="server" ID="rchb1" Text="label text goes here"></telerik:RadCheckBox>
                <%--<asp:Label ID="TreatmentCenter" Text="Treatment Center" runat="server"></asp:Label>--%>
                <telerik:RadDropDownList RenderMode="Classic" DefaultMessage="Select City" DataTextField="City" ID="DDL1" runat="server"></telerik:RadDropDownList>
```

Note: RadCheckbox only supports Lightweight RenderMode so other Telerik buttons should either use their Lightweight mode too, or you should go with an asp:Checkbox and use the AssociatedControlID of the asp:Label.

On the grid columns - since AutoGenerateColumns is false, these columns are, most likely, only present on the design-time surface. Try running the page in the browser to see whether this is the case. If they are still present, review the code-behind in case events like Page_Init add programmatically columns to your grid.

Also, note that grouping adds elements (columns) to visually distinguish grouping.

As for the buttons - just wrap them in div elements, e.g.:

```
            <div>
                <telerik:RadButton ID="Confirm" Text="Confirm" runat="server" />
                <telerik:RadButton ID="MainPage" Text="Main Page" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <telerik:RadButton ID="PosterPrintTitle" Text="Poster Print Title" runat="server" />
            <telerik:RadButton ID="PrintInvoice" Text="Print Invoice" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I still don't understand what the deal is with the checkbox, what's the use of `GridCheckBoxColumn`? Is there a special syntax to it? And how can I show the minimize button?

Comment: The sample you posted and I amended does not use a checkbox in the grid. The GridCheckBoxColumn is used to render checkboxes for your purposes and you can read more about it here: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/columns/column-types#gridcheckboxcolumn
and compare it with the GridClientSelectColumn http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/columns/column-types#gridclientselectcolumn

Comment: point 2, related to your other thread - review using hierarchical grids that let you expand rows to show details. In such a case you do not need checkboxes, the grid will generate an expand/collapse image button for you

Answer (score 0):

The `GridCheckBoxColumn` is for bit bound data. If you want to use checkboxes for multiselection, you have to use the `GridTemplateColumn`

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="CheckBoxColumn">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

As for the first two columns, they will not render once you run it. They are placeholders for the DetailTables